# Custom styling to Paypal Pro Woocommerce Payment area (need solution)

Tags: css, styling

Upon recently installing a plugin that makes the checkout process a bit neater, it seems to have fussed with the styling of the credit card forms. The image attached shows how it looks now. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIst0.png)

I'd like to have the CC field and the exp dates on separate lines, neatly put together.
Or - have them on the same line - as one big line, with the CC form at the beginning of the line, then the expiry and security code at the end of the line. The cards accepted image could be a bit bigger too.

The plugin itself (flux checkout) has a custom CSS input area. I just need to understand what css to put in there to make this design not look utterly terrible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well - I can't provide code because I don't know where to get said code. The website is: https://livecortex.com - and I'd like to get the payment gateway looking like this: https://ibb.co/17hk4SB